ViewPager2 has FATAL Exception on Google Pixel 3 XL
This question is about 'ViewPager2'
I trying to run a project on multiple device.
Same Logic but only 'Google Pixel 3 XL' has error about viewPager.setCurrentItem.
FragmentManager is already executing transactions <- this is a problem i got.
viewPager.setCurrentItem(itemPosition, false); <- this is a code error occured
What i should do? I cant find how to fix it.
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kftc.payinfo.android, PID: 14507
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1931)
at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1967)
at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:748)
at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$1.onPageSelected(FragmentStateAdapter.java:654)
at androidx.viewpager2.widget.CompositeOnPageChangeCallback.onPageSelected(CompositeOnPageChangeCallback.java:73)
at androidx.viewpager2.widget.CompositeOnPageChangeCallback.onPageSelected(CompositeOnPageChangeCallback.java:73)
at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ScrollEventAdapter.dispatchSelected(ScrollEventAdapter.java:431)
at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ScrollEventAdapter.notifyProgrammaticScroll(ScrollEventAdapter.java:319)
at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager2.java:659)
at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.setCurrentItem(ViewPager2.java:614)
at k.f.t.c.tu.B(HomeMainPagerFragment.java:232)

You'll need to share some code such as a [mcve] if you want any assistance.
